# How to reduce GPU memory in PyTorch while avoiding in-place operations?

Tags: python, pytorch, in-place

I am running out of GPU memory on a Transformer model I am using and I believe it is because I changed a number of in-place operations to out-of-place.

For example,
I changed `b += something` to `b = b + something`

where `b` and `something` are both PyTorch tensors.

I did this because the in-place operation (`+=`) breaks torch autograd and prevents me from perfroming back propogation. However, with out-of-place operations, I am duplicating data and I eventually run out of memory.

I tried manually deleting variables as follows:

```
b_new = b + something
del b
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

But this does not free up any GPU memory as observed from `torch.cuda.memory_allocated()`

How can I reduce my GPU memory consumption here?

Here is a toy example to illustrate my problem. I wish to have the memory performance of using in-place operations, while still being able to perform back propagation.

```
from torch import nn
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

X = torch.rand([500, 500, 512], device=device)

class SimpleNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linears = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(512, 512) for i in range(10)])
        self.mem_before = []
        self.mem_after = []
        
    def forward(self, x):
        for linear in self.linears:
            self.mem_before.append(torch.cuda.memory_allocated() /1024**2)
            # compare out-of-place versus in-place
            # x += linear(x)
            x = x + linear(x)
            self.mem_after.append(torch.cuda.memory_allocated() /1024**2)
        return x


model = SimpleNetwork()
model.to(device)

for epoch in range(10):
    output = model(X)
    # Calculate loss and do backward step
    # I can't do backward step with in-place operations
```

Below I have plotted the GPU memory usage for each method.

[image: in-place]
[image: out-of-place]

Comment: You can’t avoid high memory usage with autograd. Some operations require access to their arguments for backprop, so `del` won’t work. The surest and easiest way to reduce memory is to reduce the batch size. Have you tried that?

Comment: My batch size is 1

Comment: Please give a reproducible example, post your code and one training example (since you use batch size 1, that's enough)

Comment: I've added a toy example now. The original code is too complicated.

Comment: You can try to cast the network weights to float16 or use mixed precision training (amp module). Also, you could try Pytorch 2.0 (still in beta) which provides new optimisations (`torch.compile`) and may help you decrease the memory pressure.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try reducing your input size. For example, in NLP it’s not uncommon to exclude sentences longer than a certain threshold at training time because the memory consumption is proportional to length squared. Maybe you can do something similar here. Hard to say more if we don’t know what your input shape represents. Also, is the posted linear layer the part that consumes memory the most?